# How to connect Pi to an Android phone through WiFi Direct?

Tags: wifi, android, p2p, wifi-direct

I am trying to connect Raspberry Pi with a Samsung Galaxy S3 through WiFi Direct. The online information on such process is quite sparse. The most close reference I can find is from 
[CodeMonkeyRicky's Youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6GPv8TfZqe4) for Realtek 8188cu chips. He points to a good github repository [ninjablocks/rtl8192cu](https://github.com/ninjablocks/rtl8192cu). However the video is not complete (Part2 is missing). And I encountered runtime errors (segmentation fault) after compiling and running P2P_UI.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you run this?

```
sudo ./P2P_UI wlan0
```

Then enter 'e' '1' to enable wifi direct
enter 'a' to scan wifi direct devices, it should display some wifi direct devices, such as android devices

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit late, but maybe this will help others in the future. I was able to get this to work using the methods I got from this question:
[Issue connecting raspberry pi to android via Wifi p2p](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/117150/issue-connecting-raspberry-pi-to-android-via-wifi-p2p). I also made a config script that sets everything up that is available on github, it's linked in the above question. I plan to write code that automatically connects and sends data as well but for now I just have the config script