# Connect raspberry pi to mobile through wifi dongle peer-to-peer

Tags: raspicam

I want to get access to raspberry pi through my mobile. I want to shoot video from raspberry pi camera and get live stream on my mobile through wifi. There is various methods available to get stream from web browser but i don't want that i want to connect peer-to-peer from Rpi and mobile..
Plz help me in this. 
thank you...

Comment: "Peer-to-peer" networking is sort of an ambiguous high level concept.  If you *don't* want to use a web browser, you should explain exactly what software you do want to use on the phone.  Most "peer-to-peer" video networking apps are proprietary things such as Skype, and no you cannot watch the feed using Skype.  These really only make sense for two-way feeds.  Commonplace one-way video stream viewing software such as VLC are *not* peer-to-peer, they are client-to-server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to connect Pi to an Android phone through WiFi Direct?](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/10128/how-to-connect-pi-to-an-android-phone-through-wifi-direct)

Comment: thank you for response, i want to create an mobile application on witch i can see video streaming of rpi camera. so only my camera is able to access that video

Comment: UV4L is controlled via a HTTP/HTTPS Web interface (which can usually be opened by a browser or even via command line line ) but does NOT require a browser itself on the Rpi for the streaming. It does not require an X server at all to run, as video streams from remote peers are drawn onto the hdmi screen directly. I can hardly find anything similar to UV4L.

Answer (score 2):

To achieve a video stream between the Pi and your mobile phone will require a reasonable bandwidth for data.  As such, a good network connection will be required.  For Pi <--> phone connection, there are two choices ... WiFi and Bluetooth.  To the best of my knowledge, Bluetooth won't have the bandwidth that you need.  So let us focus on WiFi.  If your phone can be a WiFi hotspot, then you can enable that and configured your Pi to join your phone's WiFi hotspot environment.  At that point, the Pi and the phone will be part of a local area network and TCP/IP connections between the two will be possible.

If your phone can't be a hotspot or you wish to investigate an alternative, the Pi itself can be a hotspot using the "hostapd" technology.  At that point, your phone could join the WiFi network exposed by the Pi.  In both cases, the Pi and the phone will be able to form TCP/IP connections.  From there, the next challenge will be to find a suitable software package that would allow video streaming from the Pi to the phone.  It is possible the "motion" application running on the Pi might be able to do what you need.

Comment: I agree with most of this except the bit about `motion` -- the primary purpose of that is not to stream but to trigger recording, and it seems a pointless complication (and probably adds latency if it does stream).  You can easily set up an HTTP based streaming server [using `uv4l`](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/50344/5538).

Comment: it's not the the embedded streaming server the cool thing UV4L. It's that it can do 2-way audio/video to Janus or Jitsi gateways on internet which others can reach through their mobiles or browsers. Fantastic.

Answer (score 1):

See [UV4L](http://linux-projects.org). It's the best software out there.