# Create new secure ad-hoc network

Tags: networking, wifi, wpa, wpa-supplicant

I am trying to create a secure ad-hoc network generated from a pi 3b+ running Buster. I would like to have a password prompt to show up when I try to connect to the network on various devices. Here is what my interfaces file looks like:

```
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
  address IP
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  wireless-channel 1
  wireless-essid Network
  wireless-mode ad-hoc
  wireless-key KeyHere
```

I have also tried modifying the wpa_supplicant.conf file to add my password like so:

```
network={
    ssid="Network"
    psk="password"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```

And in my interfaces file I used:

```
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
  address IP
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  wireless-channel 1
  wpa_conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

But the network stopped showing up on my phone.

**Update** with info from a comment:
I'm using Buster. I connect to this network on my iPhone. I don't run an access point from my phone. The ad-hoc network is generated from the Pi. This is a Wifi-Direct connection.

Comment: What operating system, what version do you use? What does it mean: "*I select the network on my phone*" - do you run an access point on your iPhone? Or what is this network on your iPhone? What ad-hoc connection do you try to use? Is it IBSS? WiFi-Direct?

Comment: I'm using Buster. I connect to this network on my iPhone. I don't run an access point from my phone. The ad-hoc network is generated from the Pi. This is a Wifi-Direct connection.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use **WiFi-Direct** so you do not have to worry about security. [WiFi-Direct uses WPA2 encryption by default](https://www.wi-fi.org/discover-wi-fi/security).

You are using old style Debian networking managed with `/etc/network/interfaces`. This is deprecated on the Raspberry Pi OS based on Buster since years. I haven't used it for a long time so I cannot help much with it. I'm afraid you are alone with it.

> The ad-hoc network is generated from the Pi

This is not seen with your settings in `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`. There you have to define some options specific to WiFi-Direct.

> I would like to have a password prompt to show up when I try to connect to the network on various devices.

WiFi-Direct uses two authorization methods: "*pin entry*" and "*push button*". So for your application you have to use the pin entry method. This is done with commands using **wpa_cli**. I do not have an iPhone but an Android Phone so I can only give an example with it. You may have a look at [Connect Android smartphone with Wi-Fi Direct to a Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/117239/79866). This will give you an idea how WiFi-Direct works. The settings and using `wpa_cli` on the Raspberry Pi should not make a difference, in particular the options in `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` and the commands with `wpa_cli`.